# SSRS 2008 R2 Report Not Deploying Correctly

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, bids, ssrs-2008-r2

All,

I've run into a rather curious issue with deploying SSRSs reports to my ReportServer. I'm trying to deploy a report entitled "Point Compare." However, when I attempt to deploy the report, I get the following error:

[image: Looks like a simple issue]

So, no big deal, right? I go to deploy the shared datasets, and this message pops up:

[image: Apparently they already exist!]

Looks like SSRS thinks both that the datasets exist and that they don't exist on the ReportServer. I went into the configuration and double-checked my URLs (they were correct), and then I went out the the report server, and the datasets do indeed exist on the server in the correct location. To complicate matters further, I had a friend deploy the report for me, and he could deploy both the datasets and the report with no error.

Any ideas where this error is coming from and how to solve it?

**EDIT:** Added requested image
[image]

Comment: The "Skipping" messages don't have anything to do with the server, you can ignore them - they simply mean that the RSDs have not changed since the last time you built the project.  Can you post a screenshot of your deployment configuration?  (you might want to scrub out the server path).

Comment: Deployment config is up - as you can see, OverwriteDatasets is true as well.

Comment: Baffling.  Does the account you're deploying with have access to the Datasets folder?

Comment: It does - just had my dbadmin check it for me. Today, however, the problem is gone - I can deploy like normal. Hope it never happens again...thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this isn't much of an answer - I logged on today, and I could deploy reports normally - seems like the issue fixed itself. Must've been an internal bug in SSRS.

Comment: Just curious, did it start working after your friend deployed the datasets for you?

Comment: Sadly, no. The reports worked fine on the server once he deployed, but my box was still unable to deploy. I still haven't figured out why I was suddenly able to deploy again - didn't update SSRS or anything.